# Web page shows international characters as � on live site, but it worked on localhost

Tags: html, character-encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why my page cannot display é, instead, showing � ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477714/why-my-page-cannot-display-e-instead-showing)

I have following in my html head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

but nevertheless my live web page shows the international characters as little squares `�` or question marks `?`.

Comment: Are you sure that the text file really is saved using UTF-8 encoding? If so, make sure that you upload the file in 'binary mode' if you use FTP.

Comment: @Pekka, thanks. It was indeed a duplicate question and I found the problem. After saving the file again in Notepad+ and uploading it to the live site, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

copying [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477714/why-my-page-cannot-display-e-instead-showing/6477864#6477864) to the question [Why my page cannot display é, instead, showing �](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6477714/112968)

> make sure your file does not have a BOM (byte order mark) at its beginning. i had this problem recently, and even though the file was saved as utf8 (checked several times), the BOM confused firefox and it wrongly displayed umlauts (i had html  tags set to the correct encoding and http headers)

my website worked fine on localhost too, but broke on my webhost