# In Javascript, my text field does not recognize special symbols in a name (é character)

Tags: javascript, html

[This is the way the name shows up in the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM3iX.jpg)

But the name is coming from the database where it is stored corectly, as Ameli***é***

index.js file:

```
<div>
              <Modal
                isOpen={Overlay}
                style={customStyles}
                contentLabel="modal"
              >
                <div className="download--content">
                  <div id="download-title">Please make sure Information is Correct...</div>
                  <form id="download-form" onSubmit={(event) => this.handleSubmit(event)}>
                    <div className="product-info">
                      <Input
                        errorMessage='Please enter a valid Street Address'
                        error={cfcDeclaration.companyAddress1Error}
                        title="Street Address"
                        type="text"
                        name="Street Address"
                        value={typeof selectedCompany == 'undefined' ? "" : selectedCompany.streetAddress1}
                        disabled='edit'
```

What is the best way to correct this so the "é" and other symbols are displayed as they are in the database?

Comment: maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477714/why-my-page-cannot-display-%C3%A9-instead-showing

Comment: Looks like an encoding problem. Please show us all the code along the path from the database to the text field, especially the database connection and the http response encoding.

Comment: Is `<meta charset='UTF-8' />` in your `<head></head>`? Make sure you save the file as `UTF-8` as well.

Comment: Yes, I tried with both utf-8 and utf-16, no luck..

Answer (score 0):

Try using `BLOB` as the datatype for that specific column, It allows special characters.

Also if your browser is having issues displaying that text on its own, try using this snippet inside of your head tags.

```html
<meta charset='UTF-8'/>
```

or

```html
<meta charset='UTF-16'/>
```

depends on what you expect the user to enter