# XML charactor encoding issues with accents

Tags: php, mysql, xml, character-encoding, html-entities

I have had the problem a few times now while working on projects and I would like to know if there's an elegant solution.

**Problem**
I am pulling tweets via XML from twitter and uploading them to my DB however when I output them to screen I get these characters:

> "moved to dusseldorf.â��"
>   OR
>   tambiÃ©n

and if I have Russian characters then I get lots of ugly boxes in place.

What I would like is the correct native accents to show under one encoding. I thought was possible with UTF-8.

**What I am using**

- PHP, MYSQL

After reading in the XML file I am doing the following to cleanse the data:

```
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = htmlentities($data);
    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
```

My Database Collation is: utf8_general_ci

Web page character set is: charset=UTF-8

I think it could have something to do with HTML entities but I really appreciate a solution that works across the board on projects.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
$data = htmlentities($data);
```

With this:

```
$data = htmlentities($data, null, "UTF-8");
```

That way, htmlentities() will leave valid UTF-8 characters alone. For more information see [the documentation for htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your connection's encoding to UTF-8 (it's usually iso-8859-1). See here: [How can I store the '€' symbol in MySQL using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969583/how-can-i-store-the-symbol-in-mysql-using-php/5969626#5969626)

Calling `htmlentities()` is unnecessary when you get the encodings right. I would remove it completely. You'll just have to be careful to use `htmlspecialchars()` when *outputting* the data a in HTML context.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you set your php internal encoding ot UTF8 using [iconv_set_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-set-encoding.php), and that you call `htmlentities` with the encoding information as EdoDodo said. Also make sure that you're database stores with UTF8-encoding, though you say that's already the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `htmlentities()` in it's default state for XML data, because this function produces HTML entities, not XML entities.

The difference is that the HTML DTD defines a bunch of entity codes which web browsers are programmed to interpret. But most XML DTDs don't define them (if the XML even has a DTD).

The only entitity codes that are available by default to XML are `&gt;`, `&lt;` and `&amp;`. All other entities need to be presented using their numeric entity.

PHP doesn't have an `xmlentities()` function, but if you read [the manual page for `htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), you'll see in the comments that that plenty of people have had this same issue and have posted their solutions. After a quick browse through it, I'd suggest looking at the one named `philsXMLClean()`.

Hope that helps.