# How to get the Euro Symbol in PHP & MySQL correctly

Tags: php, mysql, excel, euro

I have an Excel file in which there are currency symbols. When I upload that file using PHP in my database it makes the Euro Symbol i.e '€' like '¬'. I have kept the collation for the currency symbol as utf8-general-ci.

Also when i tried echoing the value from Excel it prints as '¬' instead of '€'

Kindly help to fix this.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969583/how-can-i-store-the-symbol-in-mysql-using-php

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");` in your php code.

Also take a look to this question [How can I store the '€' symbol in MySQL using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969583/how-can-i-store-the-symbol-in-mysql-using-php)

Comment: Ok, my suggestion is not to use excel file but a csv or txt file. You don't want to mess with Microsoft's encoding. Also check that your file is saved with the correct encoding options. I don't think that your problem is the database because i use the same db collation to save currencies.

Comment: How can i check the encoding of my excel file?

Comment: I can not walk you through all the excel versions, a general flow goes like that Options -> advance options -> web options (encoding). Also take a look in php `mb_string` and `iconv` libraries for ways to convert a string's encoding and check if the library, you are using, for parsing excel file supports any encoding options