# Fetch currency symbol from mysql database in php

Tags: php

Create new database with `CHARSET=utf8` and in that i insert currency symbols.
When i try to fetch data with symbol using `mysql_fetch_object` but it can't display properly.
I already add utf8 charset at header as below.

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

But it's not display currency symbol.when i write that symbol on page than it's display but not from database.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5969626/1960712) should help you.

Comment: Just do the following:

In `php.ini` set `default_charset = "utf-8"`

The above will change the default character set for PHP to utf-8.

Also change the character set for Apache in `httpd.conf` as below:

`AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`

Then restart Apache and hopefully your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Well I gonna say that UTF8 is quite a pain where-you-think with PHP since it's no natively supported (R.I.P PHP6) and there can be some steps to do so you can "fully" support utf-8 in your content :

1 - First, be sure that the script displaying your content is encoded as UTF-8 (no BOM).

2 - With mysql_*, you can specify

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);
```

with

```
$link = mysql_connect(...);
```

3 - It's not UTF-8 related but please switch off mysql_* functions which are deprecated now and that can cause security issues. Have a look at PDO

4 - With SQL, you can specify that you want transactions to be in UTF-8 :

```
SET NAMES UTF-8
```

and eventually

```
SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=UTF-8
```

Comment: PHP handles UTF-8 just as well as any other language and has the same issues and most other languages. The only issue with "not natively supported" is that you may have to use some specialised functions when slicing or otherwise manipulating strings, instead of being able to use language primitives like `$string[0]`.

Comment: @deceze sorry, was my thought but now I realize it wasn't clear enough, thanks for noticing it :)

Comment: Also the encoding in MySQL is called `utf8`, not `UTF-8`. You should also consider `utf8mb4`.