# Symbols Cannot be posted with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i have a inline editing on table. if the table contains special chars and symbols ajax cannot post it properly

TABLE.PHP

```
<script>
    function showEdit(editableObj) {
        $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF");
    } 

    function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
        $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
        $.ajax({
            url: "saveedit.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
            success: function(data){
                $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
            }        
       });
    }
    </script>

<td style="vertical-align:top" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'PNAME','<?php echo $faq[$k]["ID"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["MSG"]; ?></td>
```

SAVEEDIT.PHP

```
<?php
require_once("DBcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$editval = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["editval"]);
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE ARTICLE SET " . $_POST["column"] . " = '$editval' WHERE  ID=".$_POST["id"]);?>
```

I WANT POST "Spine Tenderness ↓+, LS & Rt.Gluteal regions, Muscle spasm ↓+, ROM pain ↓ & improved" THIS CONTENT IN TABLE TO SAVEEDIT.PHP AND UPDATE IT IN DATABASE

Comment: Have you tried this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969583/how-can-i-store-the-%E2%82%AC-symbol-in-mysql-using-php

Comment: Yes i tried @AhmedGinani

Comment: What's error you fetching using that ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps if you want to store spacial char in database table.

step1: change your table's Collation- utf8_unicode_ci

step2: Also change fields Collation - utf8_unicode_ci

Step3: Go to the your db config file

Step4: After connecting to the database put following code.

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); // or

mysql_query("utf8");
```

That's all. Hope it will help